# Bulk data load into Azure Databricks sql warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have 50 tables of data under **RawData** directory in ADLS. I want to load all tables into the Azure Databricks Sql warehouse. Instead of one table at a time, I want to load all at once.
Is there a way to load this? Any idea, please?

Comment: In which format data is present in Adls?

Comment: Hey i guess you  use the Databricks Delta Lake format and the COPY INTO command to  load multi tables from your RawData directory in ADLS into the Azure Databricks SQL warehouse.

Comment: I want to load all tables at a time. Is create volume option helps?

Answer (score 0):

I agree With @Mohamed Azarudeen Z The `COPY INTO` SQL command lets you load data from a file location into a Delta table.

You will need to configure a SQL warehouse to use a Azure Databricks service principal so that you can access your source files in **ADLS Gen2**.

If you are using the Databricks Unity Catalog Know more how to  [Load data using COPY INTO with Unity Catalog volumes or external locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/copy-into/unity-catalog).

As you mentioned You need you need to **BULK LOAD** data from ADLS  you will need few [admin previlages and configure to access data for ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/copy-into/configure-data-access)

**Step 1:** You will need to create Databricks SQL warehouse
You will need The Can manage permission on the SQL warehouse and the path to your data in an ADLS Gen2 container.

```
select  *  from csv.abfss://folder02@synpadgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/dbo.employees.csv
```

***NOTE: COPY INTO support for multiple source file formats: CSV, JSON, XML, Avro, ORC, Parquet, text, and binary files***

**Step 2:** You have to create create a table in your Azure Databricks workspace to hold the incoming data.

```
CREATE TABLE <catalog_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name> (
  tpep_pickup_datetime  TIMESTAMP,
  tpep_dropoff_datetime TIMESTAMP,
  trip_distance DOUBLE,
  fare_amount DOUBLE,
  pickup_zip INT,
  dropoff_zip INT
);
```

**Step 3:** In this step using COPY INTO method to load data from an ADLS Gen2 container into the table in your Azure Databricks workspace.

```
COPY INTO <catalog-name>.<schema-name>.<table-name>
FROM 'abfss://<container>@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder>'
FILEFORMAT = CSV
FORMAT_OPTIONS (
  'header' = 'true',
  'inferSchema' = 'true'
);

SELECT * FROM <catalog-name>.<schema-name>.<table-name>;
```

Comment: I want to load all tables at a time. Is create volume helps?

Comment: Yes you can try that